# Dolphin browser, html5 no sound?

Tags: dolphin-browser

I am playing a game which is built on html5, there are sounds and work perfectly on desktop. But when I tried to open in dolphin, there is no sound, and disabling the jetpack option gives a JavaScript error even though js is enabled.

Comment: Ahh, and it's just not with dolphin, but other browsers too. Can I enable chrome to access local files, which I could do on desktop mode?